# Is core.autoclrf=true a superset of core.autocrlf=input?

Tags: git, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

From the documentation here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#__code_core_autocrlf_code ,
I can conclude that `core.autoclrf=true` does exactly what `core.autoclrf=input` (which is to convert files to LF when adding to the index) plus converting to CRLF on checkout.

However the doc is not explicit about this, so I would like to validate whether this is true.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation in the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreautocrlf) is much more concise

> Setting this variable to "true" is the same as setting the `text` attribute to "auto" on all files and core.eol to "crlf". Set to true if you want to have CRLF line endings in your working directory and the repository has LF line endings. This variable can be set to *input*, in which case no output conversion is performed.

And for what the [`text`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_text_code) attribute does

> This attribute enables and controls end-of-line normalization. When a text file is normalized, its line endings are converted to LF in the repository.

So your intuition is correct. `core.autocrlf=input` normalizes all files to LF endings in the index, while `core.autocrlf=true` additionally forces CRLF endings in your working directory.